# Change Permalink of content type

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress that has several different content types.  I have a spanish version of the site, and in some cases I need to change the permalink structure to match the language.

For example, one content type is a product.  Currently the permalink structure is as follows:

http://www.example.com/product/product-name/

however I would need to make it:

http://www.example.com/productos/product-name/

I tried to set it in the initial "register_post_type" method under "rewrite".  It didn't seem to do anything.

How can I make this change?

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

Try specifically setting the "slug" value under "rewrite":

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'productos' )
```

If it still doesn't work, make sure to flush your WP cache if you have one activated.